# Why does my code run twice in the completion block

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, completionhandler

I have some code that connects to a firebase and when it gets to a certain part of the code it runs it twice it also does not remove my waitAlertController it is causing my code to crash because it runs it twice then the second time there are no values because the first time it ran it deleted them here is my code

this is my table view where I add the wait view controller and start the completion methods.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Accept Bet", message: "Match the bet of " + amountBets[indexPath.row], preferredStyle: .alert)

    let okButton = UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: .default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
        print("Ok button tapped")
    })

    let yesButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: .default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
        // let them know to wait a second or the bet won't go through
        var waitController = UIAlertController(title: "Please Wait", message: "Your bet is being processed", preferredStyle: .alert)

        self.present(waitController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        //take away the usersMoney
        self.takeAwayMoney(self.amountBets[indexPath.row],index: indexPath.row, completion: { (result: Bool?) in

            guard let boolResult = result else {
                return
            }
            var getResult = ""
            print("You have taken away the users money")

                print("you made it this far almost there")
                //let delayInSeconds = 3.0 // 1
                //DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + delayInSeconds) { // 2
        })
        if (self.userHasMoney == true) {
        self.updateBet(indexPath.row, completion: { (result: Bool?) in

            guard let checkRes = result else {
                return
            }


        })

        self.getOpoosingUserNames(self.userName, indexPath.row, completion: { (anothaResult: Bool?) in

            guard let value = anothaResult else {
                return print("didn't work")
            }
                    //wait for the first view to load in case it uploads to fast
                    sleep(1)
                    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                    let successController = UIAlertController(title: "Success", message: "You have made a bet with " + self.opposingUserNames!, preferredStyle: .alert)
                    let okButt = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil)
                    successController.addAction(okButt)
                    self.present(successController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    //lastly delete the opposing UserName
                    self.amountBets.remove(at: indexPath.row)
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                    print("Second")

        })
        } else {
            //display a alert that lets the user know hes broke
            let brokeController = UIAlertController(title: "Failed", message: "Reason: You don't have enough money!", preferredStyle: .alert)
            let okButt = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil)
            brokeController.addAction(okButt)
            self.present(brokeController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

    return
    })

    alertController.addAction(okButton)
    alertController.addAction(yesButton)
    present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

and this is my takeMoneyAway method

```
func takeAwayMoney(_ howMuch: String, index: Int, completion: @escaping (Bool)-> ()) -> Void{
        if let notMuch = Int(howMuch) {

            let userID = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid

            datRef.child("User").child(userID!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
                // Get user value
                let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
                let money = value?["money"] as? String ?? ""

                //convert money to int
                if let conMoney = Int(money) {
                    var conMoreMoney = conMoney
                    if conMoreMoney < notMuch {
                        print(" You don't have enough money")
                        completion(false)
                        return
                    } else {
                        conMoreMoney -= notMuch
                        let values = ["money": String(conMoreMoney)]

                        //update the users money
                        self.datRef.child("User").child(userID!).updateChildValues(values)
                        completion(true)
                        /*
                        self.updateBet(index, completion: { (result: Bool?) in
                            guard let checkResult = result else {
                                return print("Failed to get result")
                            }
                            if checkResult == true {
                                completion(true)
                            } else {
                                completion(false)
                            }
                        })
 */

                    }

                }
                // ...
            }) { (error) in
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }
```

and my final method goes to my database updates the values and grabs the person they made a bet against.

```
 func updateBet(_ index: Int, completion: @escaping (_ something: Bool?) -> Void) {
        let userID = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid
        datRef.child("User").child(userID!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            // Get user value
            let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
            // ...


            self.datRef.child("Bets").observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in
                //
                // this is the unique identifier of the bet.  eg, -Kfx81GvUxoHpmmMwJ9P
                guard let dict = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyHashable] else {
                    print("failed to get dictionary from Bets.\(self.userName)")
                    return
                }
                let values = ["OpposingUsername": self.userName,"Show": "no"]


                self.datRef.child("Bets").child(self.tieBetToUser[index]).updateChildValues(values)
                let checkTheCodeWentHere = "Success"
                // now get the opposing username which is just the Username registered to that specific bet

                self.datRef.child("Bets").child(self.tieBetToUser[index]).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
                    let thisValue = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
                    if let username = thisValue?["Username"] as? String {
                        self.opposingUserNames = username
                        completion(true)
                    } else {
                        completion(false)
                    }

                })

            })

        }) { (error) in
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }


    }
```

so in the tableview method there is a block of code that says if checkRes == true {}
all of the code in the curly braces runs twice I checked this with break points can some one tell me why this is?

Comment: Can you post your console logs from a single session showing the output from your `print` statements?

Comment: it will show all of the the print statements about 20 times each @Fahim I updated the code in my xcode and now it works. I guess you can't nest completion functions

Comment: oh I tested that in break points I don't remember but I am pretty sure that it wasn't. One thing that I can't figure out now is I need somthing different to happen if one of the completion functions return false. for example my first function takes away money from the user. So if the user has no money then the function will return false but the functions will still run below it. I even tried setting a boolean value then checking if that boolean is false and if it is then don't run the other completion blocks @Fahim

Comment: Usually, if you have two different results from an action in a closure, the easiest thing to do is to pass it two closures - one for success, one for failure. Then depending on what happens in the closure, you call either the success block or the failure block.

Comment: so how would I prevent the other blocks from running if the failureblock is the one executed @Fahim ill just update my code to show you what I mean

Comment: You do a check within the bit of code where you can have success for failure and then if the code succeeded, you call the success block or failure otherwise. Can't really tell you much more without actually going through your code line by line and you have a lot of code :)

Comment: yeah I know sorry lol so I updated the tableView method in my question. I can upload my entire class if you like but there is lots of random code that does nothing that I haven't deleted so it would be very confusing also I am not using MVC yet @Fahim

Comment: If you can upload the project somewhere and provide the link, I can run the code, figure out what is going on and give you an example of how to do the failure and success blocks.

Comment: https://github.com/devintrippprojects/EDraft after figuring out how to use github for the first time I think I uploaded it all correctly to there @Fahim

Comment: It compiled without any issues - so looks good. Will take a look after lunch and get back to you.

Comment: Is there a test account that I can use to log in to the app?

Comment: You can create your own it gives you 100 money's

Answer (score 1):

Without being able to actually run the code and test it, and based solely on your comments above, I believe the part you were talking about was this:

```
//take away the usersMoney
self.takeAwayMoney(self.amountBets[indexPath.row],index: indexPath.row, completion:{(result) in
    if result {
        // User has money
    } else {
        // User does not have money
    }
    var getResult = ""
    print("You have taken away the users money")

        print("you made it this far almost there")
        //let delayInSeconds = 3.0 // 1
        //DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + delayInSeconds) { // 2
})
```

The `takeAwayMoney` method returns whether the user has money or not via the `result` parameter of the closure and that parameter wsan't an optional in the method definition. However, in the above code, for some reason it was declared an optional. I have changed the code to remove that bit of code and added an `if` condition indicating how you would proceed after `takeAwayMoney` has been executed.

Basically, you first call `takeAwayMoney`, wait for that method to return its results via the closure, and then look at the results of the closure and do any subsequent processing. So, it looks as if you really need all the code within the `if (self.userHasMoney == true) {` condition to be moved to be within the `takeAwayMoney` completion closure.

Hope this makes sense. If not, feel free to ping me and I'll try to clarify.

Comment: but if I do that then I will have nested closures and the code will run 10 times

Comment: @DevinTripp Nope, just nesting closures does not make them run multiple times. They would run multiple times only if there was an issue with how the code was set up :) So, I'd suggest you set up the way I mentioned and see what happens. If you urn into issues, update the code on GitHub and let me know and I'll take a look.